# Do individual button in Angularjs retain their own copy of the function in their scope?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, animate.css

I have a pretty simple button that tests an error message but turning it on in AngularJS (using no-show)—all of the classes are for bootstrap and animate.css

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible bounceInUp animated" role="alert" ng-show="isErrorOn">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" ng-click="toggleError()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>

<a class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="toggleError()">Test Error Message</a>
```

Within the main controller are the following variables and instructions:

```
$scope.isErrorOn = false;

$scope.toggleError = function() {
    if( $scope.isErrorOn === true ) {
        $scope.isErrorOn = false;
    } else {
        $scope.isErrorOn = true;
    }
};
```

The behavior is as follows: when the page is opened, the error is not there. When the "Test error message" button is pressed, the error appears. Press it again and the error goes away, ad infinitum. However, if you open the error and then use the error's own dismiss button to make it go away, the "Test Error Message" button ceases to operate. Is this because two copies of `$scope.isErrorOn` have been created or am I just missing something else?

Comment: Probably you are missing something, I've created a jsfiddle with your code and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/8qdts6uz/

Comment: Are you using `ui.bootstrap` or loading the bootstrap javascript?  Either is probably handling the alert's dismiss button and using a different method to hide the alert so that `ng-show` will have no effect.

Comment: Oh! You were right on the nose. I commented out the bootstrap.js file and everything is working fine. Thanks!